# python requests issues with non ascii data

Tags: python, http, encoding, python-requests, mailgun

I'm having problem using non-ascii characters in a file I'm trying to send as an attachment using requests.

The exception pops at httplib module in the _send_output function.
see this image:

[image]

here is my code:

```
response = requests.post(url="https://api.mailgun.net/v2/%s/messages" % utils.config.mailDomain,
                auth=("api", utils.config.mailApiKey),
                data={
                        "from" : me,
                        "to" : recepients,
                        "subject" : subject,
                        "html" if html else "text" : message
                    },
                files= [('attachment', open(f)) for f in attachments] if attachments and len(attachments) else []   


            )
```

The problem is with the files parameter, containing non ascii data (hebrew).
The exception as can be seen in the image is:

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 673: ordinal not in range(128)**

Answer (score 1):

the `open()` function [has a parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open) `encoding`, used like `f = open('t.txt', encoding='utf-8')` which accepts [a variety of parameters](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode) as outlined in the docs. Find out what encoding scheme your data uses (probably UTF-8) and see if opening with that encoding works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the encoding parameter to open the files because you want to open them as binary data. The calls to open should look like `open(f, 'rb')`. The documentation for requests only shows examples like this purposefully and even documents this behaviour.